# Calculate position with distance and coordinates in Java

Tags: java, math

I have a device, let's call it the origin, which sends a signal to other machines, let's call them satellites. For each satellite I know its position and the distance from the origin.

```
Satellite position 1: [-500, -200].
Satellite position 2: [100, -100].
Satellite position 3: [500, 100].

Satellite distance 1: 100.0
Satellite distance 2: 115.5
Satellite distance 3: 142.7
```

Supposedly the position of the origin is:

```
x: -100.0
y: 75.5
```

I say supposedly because I don't know if it really is, I don't know how to calculate this.

I had seen this library: https://github.com/lemmingapex/Trilateration. But the result it gives me is a bit different from what I expected.

With the library, i try this:

```
double[][] positions = new double[][] { { -500.0, -200.0 }, { 100.0, -100.0 }, { 500.0, 100 } };
double[] distance = new double[] { 100.0, 115.5, 142.7 };

NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver solver = new NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver(new TrilaterationFunction(positions, distances), new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());
Optimum optimum = solver.solve();
    
double[] centroid = optimum.getPoint().toArray();
```

And the result is [-58.315252587138595, -69.55141837312165], not [-100, 75.5].

The thing is, I don't know if I'm using the right function or if I got the answer wrong.

Comment: Well, the satellite at (-500, -200) distance from (-100, 75.5) is much larger than 100.

Comment: Being in a not bended 2-dimensional space your positions and distances are not possible, I think